# navigationController pushViewController not working in iOS11 but works in iOS9.3

Tags: ios11

The following piece of code works in iOS10 but not iOS11. Any idea why?

```
    SiteSelectionViewController *sitesController;
    sitesController = [[SiteSelectionViewController alloc] init];
    [sitesController setConfData:self.confData];
    [sitesController setConfInitData:self.confInitData];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:sitesController animated:YES];
    [sitesController release];
```

I expect to see SiteSelectionViewController view to show but it didn't. I tried to change to "animated:NO" as some have suggested but it didn't work. Again the same code works in iOS 9.3 simulator. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to push controller in DispatchQueue.main.async { } block.

Answer (score 0):

Deleted the derived data folder, restarted XCODE and simulators and it started working all fine.

Seems to be a compiler / garbage issue. Restarting made all fine. Make sure to delete derive data and clean project to resolve this.